# 'Char' is not a member of 'String'" in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, decimal, rounding

Scenario is described below:

In txtDiscountRate.Text it has a value which is "0.996010500406591".

In my coding I did this:

```
txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 6)  'means considering round till 6th digit
```

It is giving the value 0.99601 because of 6th digit after decimal is 0. But I want to put a condition in the decimal value.

So if on 6th digit after decimal is ( 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 ) and 7th digit after decimal is available, then it will round until 7th position. 
Or else it will round until 6th position.

I got a solution (shown in the code below) from this site for this problem. I tried to implement but the below code throws an error:

```
CInt(Str(1).Char(5))  is showing error this error  -> " 'Char' is not a member of 'String'".
```

This is my whole code so far:

```
Dim str() As String = Split(CStr(Dec), ".")

If CInt(Str(1).**Char(5)**) < 5 Then 'It's Char number 5 since it's a zero-based index. So the first number = Index 0.
    txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 7)
Else
    txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 6)
End If
```

**Correct solution is needed.**

Comment: Yes, Mid(Str(1), 5,1 )   is removed error but, requirement is not resolved.

Comment: `Char` is indeed not a member of `String` but **[Chars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that following function will help you and it is your solution.

```
Function GetDecimalValue(ByVal value As String) As Decimal
        Dim valueFromDot As String = value.Substring(IIf(value.IndexOf(".") < 0, 0, value.IndexOf(".") + 1))
        If (valueFromDot.Length > 5) Then
            If (CInt(valueFromDot(5).ToString()) < 5 And CInt(valueFromDot(6).ToString()) > 0) Then
                GetDecimalValue = Math.Round(CDec(value), 7)
            Else
                GetDecimalValue = Math.Round(CDec(value), 6)
            End If
        Else
            GetDecimalValue = CDec(value)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Tell me one thing, can i know what is the value of Nth position digit  after decimal.                                              Ex:  78.896103456                                         in this after Decimal on 1st position: 8
                            on 2nd position:9 on 3rd position;  and so on....